# How to make "gq" wrap lines that start with a `*` without inserting more stars

Tags: vim

Consider the following long line.

```
 * Explain that core policies were created to give applications the ability to control the mapping of (user) threads to cores, and why they might want to do this.
```

Here is the current output of `gq`.

```
 * Explain that core policies were created to give applications the ability to
 * control the mapping of (user) threads to cores, and why they might want to
 * do this.
```

Here's the desired output of `gq`

```
 * Explain that core policies were created to give applications the ability to
   control the mapping of (user) threads to cores, and why they might want to
   do this.
```

Here's the current value of my `formatoptions`:

```
formatoptions=tqn
```

I looked through `:help formatoptions` and attempted to get the desired behavior by removing `c` from the options as well as `q` but neither seems to affect the output of `gq`.

One suggested answer was to remove `q` but that results in the following output (also undesirable).

```
 * Explain that core policies were created to give applications the ability to
 control the mapping of (user) threads to cores, and why they might want to do
 this.
```

Is there a way to get the desired output through some setting of `formatoptions`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
set formatoptions+=n
set comments=fb:*,fb:-
set autoindent
```

This allows list either with `*` or with `-`.

Comment: What are you assuming about the previous value of `formatoptions`?

Comment: @merlin2011 I assume the default value: `tcq`. I tested this with `vim -u NONE -N`. So default settings & no-compatible mode.